# STM32F103 RTOS Delay in between threads

Tags: stm32, keil, stm32f1, cubemx

I am creating a project using STM32F103C8T6 controller in which I am using RTOS. I have 4 threads in it. The functions in each of these threads experiences a significant amount of delay (eg: if any sensor is connected for the value to be read from the sensor or if a keypad is there the button press triggers the function after some time etc etc). Any help and support is highly appreciated...
I am using Cube MX and Keil for development

Comment: What is the question? What do you want to know?

Comment: How to reduce delay between the switching of threads??

Comment: There is no notable delay in task switching. The dealay must be wihtin our task (code).